# Crispy-Form layout with list

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am currently building a webapp in django using crispy-forms, and I was wondering, is there a way to create a layout for a form using a list of strings for the field names? Thank you.

Comment: The answer to your question with a bunch of examples is available at the crispy-forms docs at http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
list_of_field_names = ['field1', 'field2']

self.helper = FormHelper()
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Fieldset(
        'first arg is the legend of the fieldset',
        *list_of_field_names
    ),
    ...
)
```